# Photo floating over page elements?

Tags: html, css

I have a header photo, and usually they are fairly easy to set up. However, for some reason which I cannot find, the header image floats over the elements of the HTML page.

Any help would be appreciated. I have tried looking for any margins/padding I forgot to delete, but there are none.

Picture of problem...

[image]

HTML pertaining to header image:

```
<div id="gallery">

    <div id="imgContain">

        <img src="pictures/clubhouse.jpg">

    </div>

</div>
```

My CSS File: (not sure where the problem is, so I posted all of it...)

```
html, body
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-image: url('.././pictures/04.jpg');
background-color: rgb(56,32,32);

}   

@font-face
{
font-family: fancyFont;
src: url('fonts/fancy.otf');
}

#wrapper
{
min-width: 1000px;
margin: auto;
}


#content
{
background-color: white;
display: table;
border-radius: 5px;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0;
margin: auto;
right: 0;
top: 0;
width: 915px;
height: 100%;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 22px black;
}


#content p
{
padding: 25px;
font-family: Arial;
text-indent: 30px;
font-size: 1em;
word-wrap: break-word;
}

center
{
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

table
{
border: 1px solid black;
float: left;

}

.main-table /*Main table is the navigation table to the left...*/
{
background-color: white;
margin-bottom: 25px;
border: 4px double white;
width: 245px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;

}

.main-table td
{
padding: 10px;
padding-left: 15px;
}

.main-table td a
{
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
font-family: Arial;
transition: .2s;
font-size: .9em;
padding-left: 20px;
}

.main-table td a:hover
{
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
color: black;
padding-left: 50px;
transition: .2s;
}

.main-table h1
{
font-family: fancyFont;
padding:10px;
color: black;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px white;
}

.division /*Division(s) are the small info boxes in the center.*/
{
margin-top: px;
margin-left: 40px;
border: none;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.division th
{
width: 250px;
background-color: white;
border-bottom: 3px double black;
padding: 10px;
font-family: fancyFont;
}

.division tr td
{

display: inline-block;
width: 250px;
height: 100px;
max-width: 250px;

}

#gallery
{
width: 100%;
height: 100px;


}

#gallery h1
{
font-family: fancyFont;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #acacac;

}

#gallery img
{
width: 100%;
height: 450px;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;

}

table ul li
{
list-style: square;
font-family: Arial;

}

#imgContain
{
background-color: white;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#table-container
{
width: 900px;
margin: 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take out the

```
#gallery{height:100px;}
```

css because your gallery img height is 450px and the two conflict.

Answer (score 0):

An element will "float" over another element when the floating element's position is set to absolute. I don't see position: absolute; in your CSS, but I do see positioning styles (bottom: 0px; left: 0; etc.) so maybe another style sheet is applying position: absolute. Best way would be to inspect the elements using a browser inspector like Firefox has and see what CSS styles are being applied. You can send me the URL and I will look at it. If you just want to throw a dart at the board you could try setting this style:

```
#gallery {
  position: static !important;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. I previously had a position: absolute, but got rid of it during trouble-shooting. 

I would send you the URL, but I can't, haha. Site is still on my local-host. 

I set the position to static, but it doesn't effect the issue. Also, there shouldn't be any other styles effecting the situation. This page has it's own set of styles, and it is only linked to them.

EDIT: Inspector doesn't show any position: absolute either...

Comment: Can you post your HTML and CSS? I'm willing to look at it. I'm new to stackexchange, so I don't know the protocol for this kind of thing. Also, thought stackexchange would email me when you commented; guess I need to keep an eye on things!

Answer (score 0):

Floating generally happens when `position: absolute` is set in CSS, but strangely, it's not your case.
So, you can try to add a CSS property to this image, called `z-index` with the value of `-1`. It'll possibly work.

This property is a kind of "layers". By default, every element is set in `z-index: 0`.

So, basically, it'll be:

```
img {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

or, in this case:

```
#gallery {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

***Sorry if my english is bad.***

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the comment.

I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't seem to even effect the image. Also, I don't know if z-index would work, in that I need the other page elements to react to the position of the image; which they aren't doing. They act like it isn't there.

Either way, thank you for the comment. I'm not sure why Z-index didn't even effect anything. Something seems off. Haha.